# Проверка электронных адресов регулярным выражением

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, email

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не получается данным регулярным выражением отсеять строки, которые начинаются с www и некоторые строки с неверным доменом? Ссылочка на мой подбор здесь https://regex101.com/r/eU5S6g/5. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю?

UPD:
Данные в виде простого списка непроверенныз электронных адресов в Excel. Формат адресов разный, но примерно тот, что я привел по ссылке на сайте regex101.com.

Comment: Попробуйте так: https://regex101.com/r/eU5S6g/6. Кстати `www@mail.ru` - вполне себе нормальный email...

Comment: ненормальный - это {{7*7}}@mail.ru, a www@mail.ru - нормальный!

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо! Вот только не понял почему у вас работает это выражение? Та часть что идет до @ по идее ищет соответствие по любому непробельному символу, которым и www является, в моем понимании) но почему то он у вас не выделяется. Как вы так делаете?)

Comment: @DenisNovik, всё дело в наличии символа `'@'` - в WEB адресах он отсутствует

Comment: @DenisNovik, [в общем случае проверять правильность email регулярками - очень неблагодарная задача](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @MaxU, а какие тогда варианты? Через contains проверять?

Comment: @DenisNovik, в каком виде данные, которые вы хотите проверять? Можете привести пример данных в вопросе?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @MaxU. Не надо так делать. Разбирате `urllib`'ом или чем-то подобным по токенам, а дальше отдельно анализируйте каждый токен.

Comment: Попройте: https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автору для проверки валидности email подошел модуль [email_validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator).

Установка:

```
pip install email_validator
```

Пример:

```
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError

email = "my+address@mydomain.tld"

try:
    v = validate_email(email) # validate and get info
    email = v["email"] # replace with normalized form
except EmailNotValidError as e:
    # Email is not valid, exception message is human-readable
    print(e)
```

Comment: и еще нашел неплохой модуль https://github.com/michaelherold/pyIsEmail для этих же целей